# How to completely reset an ARKit scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

Hey guys I'm having a small issue with ARKit and Unity.

In the game that I'm making I'm reloading my scene when the player dies, however when the scene is reloaded all the GameObjects are still in the same position from the last session. I want all my objects to return to their starting positions when the scene is reloaded.

I saw that some variables regarding position and rotation are marked as "static" in the code. I tried changing them but I got a lot of compile errors.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

Add these lines of code in your ARCameraManager script in the "!UnityEditor" part.

```
UnityARSessionRunOption options = new UnityARSessionRunOption();
options = UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors | UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking;
m_session.RunWithConfigAndOptions(config, options);
```

Now every time you reload your scene all AR elements (planes, anchors, camera tracking data) are reset.

Comment: There is some existing code in there. Is this the right way to do this? https://imgur.com/a/7vkoU Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, the object gets placed 5 ft from instead of in front of me. 

Comment: Yep, same thing happens to me as well. Fortunately thats the way that I want it to work. Where do you want the object to be? Will it not let you move the object around the scene in the editor?

Comment: I found a better way. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Create this method and call it whenever you want to reset the scene:

```
using UnityEngine.XR.iOS;
.
.
.

public void ResetScene() {
ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration sessionConfig = new ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration ( UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravity, UnityARPlaneDetection.Horizontal);
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().RunWithConfigAndOptions(sessionConfig, UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionRemoveExistingAnchors | UnityARSessionRunOption.ARSessionRunOptionResetTracking);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have found around. However, when I build to my iphone with xcode sometimes calling the method crashes the app. Any idea?

Comment: This is a C# code to be used in Unity. Are you using swift?

Comment: No I am using c# in Unity. Do file > Build settings  and build my project out to IOS. Then load it on the phone through xcode. It crashes sometimes. Not always when this ResetScene method is called. I noticed in the Unity asset store there was an update for the ARKit. Could it be that I am using an older version now of the ARKit from the Asset store?

Comment: Must be some other issue in that case if it crashes sometimes.